# Connecting AWS RDS(mysql) from spefic ip in php:timed out error

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I was successfully launched an AWS RDS instance with public accessible is set to false

So that my RDS access only the connections from my development machine and production server

I've added the inbound rule(localhost ip) to the security group that is currently assigned to db instance.

[image]

But i will get connection timed out error

```
$servername = "xxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:3306";
$username = "x";
$password = "woola";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=xxcc", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Can you able to connect from mysql console ? `mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p` like this one ?

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: Its also give timeout error

Comment: In your security group, the source having 127.0.0.1/32 isn't that a loopback address, you should put your IP address, find out what is your IP (public IP if your RDS is in the public subnet)

Comment: @Gigapalmer how do i find RDS is publicsubnet or not?

Comment: Go to the RDS service, click on Instances, select your instance(check box), and click on the instance actions and in the list click on See Details

Comment: But there is no information about publicsubnet

Comment: Got it subnet group and subnet values are present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason :** 
You should not try with your local ip

**What you should do ?**

You should try with your  public ip

You can find your public ip by this link [Find My IP by Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=find%20my%20ip)

**Note :**

Your public ip may change if you didn't have static ip

Comment: How can i find the CIDR value of my public ip??

Comment: your ip_address/32

Comment: Have you enabled the `MYSQL/Aurora` in your security group ? It's port is `3306`

Comment: So i need two rules?? one for MYSQL/Aurora and one for all traffic??

Comment: I would suggest not to enable `All Traffic` instead open only the required one. Ex. http, mysql, ssh etc.,

Comment: Which one is fullfill my needs?

Comment: Better leave open only the `HTTP` , `SSH` and `MYSQL/Aurora`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135363/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-jabaa).

Answer (score 0):

Edit your security group and select type: MySQL/Aurora, port: 3306 and source select custom and choose 172.31.0.0/16 if your development instance is an EC2 instance. If you are trying to access from your work station, choose custom and put your public ip/32 in source field.